# Failing task if variable undefined

Tags: ant

I would like my Ant task to fail if a variable it uses is not defined.  E.g. currently

`<mkdir dir="${some.dir}"/>`

always succeeds, if `some.dir` is defined, it creates a directory under the variable's value, if not it creates a directory named literally `${some.dir}`.

Is there a way and how to switch between the currently lenient and a more strict mode of resolving variables in Ant?  I am running this in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

```
<fail unless="some.dir"/>

<mkdir dir="${some.dir}"/>
```

or

```
<fail>
    <condition>
        <not>
            <isset property="some.dir"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>

<mkdir dir="${some.dir}"/>
```

Comment: but i would have to explicitly declare that for each required var. is there a way to set ant in a strict mode to fail if any used var is not set?

Comment: @amphibient Sorry I don't know if there is such a switch. And I don't think there is, either. The `properties` in Ant is actually handled in a `Map` in the parsed `Project`. For the way Ant parses the xml into `Project`, `Target` and `Task`, I don't think it has implemented the feature to go over all the `${}`s in the xml and look each one up in the `Map`. Though most of the properties in Ant build file are declared, there are still some that are generated by some tasks during the run. That also makes it hard to check all the properties in advance.

Comment: Actually you should only check `isset` for the properties that are generated during the run. For the declared ones, you should handle the availability manually (and Eclipse may help a little by its static checking).